# Async behavior on WebForms gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

While porting a legacy application to async\await pattern we've came across some weird behavior we can't track. We set the page async directive to true, and add event handler to RowDataBound. If the code in the EventHandler contains an awaited call, it is not awaited before moving on to handle the next row.

Here is a repro to make it easier to understand:

```
public partial class WorkingCorrectlyWebForm: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int _index;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = new GridView();
        grid.RowDataBound += GridOnRowDataBound;
        grid.DataSource = new[]
        {
            new {Name = "Person1", Age = 23},
            new {Name = "Person2", Age = 33},
            new {Name = "Person3", Age = 15}
        };

        grid.DataBind();
    }

    private async void GridOnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs gridViewRowEventArgs)
    {
        if (gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            return;

        var localIndex = ++_index;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write($"starting #{localIndex} <br />");

        await Task.Delay(1000); //HERE IS THE PROBLEMATIC LINE

        //removing the remark from the following line will make code behave "synchronously" as expected.
        // Task.Delay(1000).Wait(); 

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write($"exiting #{localIndex} <br />");
    }
}
```

This code will generate output that is similiar to this (instead of ordered "starting\exiting" each item):

starting #1

starting #2

starting #3

exiting #3

exiting #1

exiting #2

Why is this happeninig? why am i not seeing an ordered "starting" and "exiting" messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want serial behaviour, this should work:

```
    private void GridOnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs gridViewRowEventArgs)
    {
        if (gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            return;

        var localIndex = ++_index;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write($"starting #{localIndex} <br />");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // or             Task.Delay(1000).Wait();


        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write($"exiting #{localIndex} <br />");
    }
```

or try:

```
    private void GridOnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs gridViewRowEventArgs)
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() => Bob(gridViewRowEventArgs)));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write($"b");

    }

    private async Task Bob(GridViewRowEventArgs gridViewRowEventArgs)
    {
        if (gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            return;

        var localIndex = ++_index;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write($"starting #{localIndex} <br />");

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write($"exiting #{localIndex} <br />");
    }
```

Comment: The await Task.Delay(1000) is just for the sake of the repro. It's meant to show that any awaitable call will not be awaited in this scenario.

Comment: Please look at the repro my question. I wrote there that this works, but my question is why "await" does not work as I expected in this scenario.

Comment: I suspect it is because you have marked the method as async. Is there a particular reason you want the method to be async?

Comment: yes, becuse it needs to await on an awaitable method.

Comment: You couldn't just use awaitableMethod.Wait() ?

Comment: In some scenarios i could, others I couldnt since it caused deadlocks.
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145882/discussion-between-mjwills-and-motime).